Advice on where to ask questions about lower-level finance questions?
I'm currently studying for the SOA's Investment and Financial Markets exam, which covers Corporate Finance and Derivatives. These topics seem to be a little too low-level to qualify for this site, and they don't really fit on math.se or money.se either. Any advice for where I can ask these kinds of questions?

Looking at https://money.stackexchange.com/ and https://www.soa.org/education/exam-req/edu-exam-ifm-detail/ - yes I think those kinds of questions would belong there.
